# Java openapi3 - cannot execute builded jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, openapi, springfox

I try to build my app into executable jar but when I try to run it I have got an error:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.6.1)

2021-12-19 03:14:39.574  INFO 8407 --- [           main] p.p.U.UnoApiBE                           : Starting UnoApiBE using Java 11.0.12 on iMac-Stefan.local with PID 8407 (/Users/stefantobiasiewicz/Documents/Programing/Java/UnoApi/target/UnoApi-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar started by stefantobiasiewicz in /Users/stefantobiasiewicz/Documents/Programing/Java/UnoApi)
2021-12-19 03:14:39.592  INFO 8407 --- [           main] p.p.U.UnoApiBE                           : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-12-19 03:14:39.943  WARN 8407 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [pl.polsl.UnoApi.UnoApiBE]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [pl/polsl/UnoApi/api/GameApi.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
2021-12-19 03:14:40.016 ERROR 8407 --- [           main] o.s.b.SpringApplication                  : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [pl.polsl.UnoApi.UnoApiBE]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [pl/polsl/UnoApi/api/GameApi.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:189) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) [spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) [spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) [spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) [spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1290) [spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at pl.polsl.UnoApi.UnoApiBE.main(UnoApiBE.java:15) [UnoApi-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [pl/polsl/UnoApi/api/GameApi.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:199) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.getClassReader(SimpleMetadataReader.java:55) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:49) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:103) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.createMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:73) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:81) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:696) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getInterfaces(ConfigurationClassParser.java:1024) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processInterfaces(ConfigurationClassParser.java:386) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:332) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:250) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:199) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:304) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:250) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:207) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:175) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        ... 13 more
```

I use openapi plugin to create api interface like this:

UnoApi.yml:

```
.
.
.
  /games:
    get:
      tags:
        - Game
      summary: Endpoint to get all games
      operationId: getGames
      responses:
        200:
          description: all games
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/Game'
.
.
.
```

And it's create me api interface:

```
@Api(
    value = "Game",
    description = "the Game API"
)
public interface GameApi {
    default Optional<NativeWebRequest> getRequest() {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    @ApiOperation(
        value = "cancel started or waiting game",
        nickname = "cancelGame",
        notes = "",
        tags = {"Game"}
    )
    @ApiResponses({@ApiResponse(
    code = 200,
    message = "game canceled"
), @ApiResponse(
    code = 400,
    message = "cannot cancel game"
)})
    @RequestMapping(
        method = {RequestMethod.POST},
        value = {"/game/{id}/cancel"}
    )
    default ResponseEntity<Void> cancelGame(@ApiParam(value = "",required = true) @PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);
    }
.
.
.
```

This is my controller:

```
@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
public class GameController implements GameApi {

    GameMapper gameMapper;
.
.
.
```

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>pl.polsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>UnoApi</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <base.package>pl.polsl.UnoApi</base.package>
        <start-class>pl.polsl.UnoApi.UnoApiBE</start-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring boot web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!-- log4j2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- test  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.202</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Swagger documentation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Open api generator dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind-nullable</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- need for spring boot while using open api generator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jpa for spring boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- postgres driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- lombok data, stter, getter generator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.22</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Mapstruct -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Mqtt queue -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-mqtt</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>
                                ${project.build.directory}/libs
                            </outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>libs/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>
                                pl.polsl.UnoApi.UnoApiBE
                            </mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Open api generator -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>5.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>api-client</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/OpenApiGen/UnoApi.yaml</inputSpec>
                                <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                                <groupId>pl.polsl</groupId>
                                <artifactId>UnoApi</artifactId>

                                <apiPackage>pl.polsl.UnoApi.api</apiPackage>
                                <modelPackage>pl.polsl.UnoApi.model</modelPackage>

                                <modelNameSuffix>Dto</modelNameSuffix>
                                <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
                                <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
                                <supportingFilesToGenerate>
                                    ApiUtil.java
                                </supportingFilesToGenerate>
                                <configOptions>
                                    <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                                    <delegatePattern>false</delegatePattern>
                                    <serializableModel>true</serializableModel>
                                    <useBeanValidation>false</useBeanValidation>
                                    <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                                    <serializationLibrary>jackson</serializationLibrary>
                                    <useTags>true</useTags>
                                </configOptions>
                            </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>1.18.22</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>1.4.2.Final</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And if I extract jar I can see this class:

[photo of extracted files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ajbzv.png)

I use java "11.0.12" 2021-07-20 LTS

Why java can't see it?

Comment: hi & welcome! "class path resource [pl/polsl/UnoApi/api/GameApi.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist" did it compile? ...

Comment: yeah, I can run app in intelij and there everything is ok

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by changing the location of the generated API.
I generated the API interface into an API package, and my controllers were also in the same package.

I move the generated API location into the `genApi` package:

```
<apiPackage>pl.polsl.UnoApi.genApi</apiPackage>
```

and that solved this problem.